# emr-6.0.0-beta2 HiveLLAP low vCore allocation and utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hadoop-yarn, daemon, amazon-emr

I have a 21 node Hive LLAP EMR cluster.
Hive LLAP Daemons not consuming available cluster VCPU allocation.
160 cores available for YARN but only 1 vCore is used per LLAP daemon.
Each Node has 64 GB memory and 8 vCores. Each node runs 1 LLAP deamon and its allocated 70% of the memory BUT ONLY 1 vCore.
Some of the properties:

```
   yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=8;
    yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores=1;
    yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores=128;
    hive.llap.daemon.vcpus.per.instance=4;
    hive.llap.daemon.num.executors=4;
```

Why isn't the daemon allocated more than 1 vcore ?
Will the executors be able to use the available vcores OR can ONLY use the 1 vcore allocated to the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this in YARN ui probably you have to add this

`yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator`

I had the same confusion. Actually while using `DefaultResourceCalculator` in Yarn UI its only calculates memory usage, behind the scene it may have been using more than 1 core but you will see only 1 core used. On the other hand `DominantResourceCalculator` calucates both core and memory for resource allocation and shows actual number of core and memory.

You can enable ganglia or see EMR metrics for more details.